# Visual Studio can not find Data over System

Tags: c++, qt, cmake, cgal

I have finally managed to install CGAL. It was a really tough journey!!

Unfortunately i have a new Problem now, Visual Studio could not start the program it says the System could not found the Data(see below). What can i do to correct the error, which settings do i have to make ?
[image]

Comment: You should set another project as "StartUp" one. Just select it from the project's context menu.

Comment: The ALL_BUILD target is not something that is executable. You need to change the startup project to one that is an application.

Comment: @vahancho Thank you so much for your help! It really worked out!

Comment: @drescherjm Thank you so much for your help! It really worked out!!